# List teamworkTags API returning 404

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to run this `GET /teams/{team-Id}/tags` api in Graph explorer, but returning 404

[image]

Also, as per the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamworktag-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http), the API requires

> Application permission | TeamworkTag.Read.All, TeamworkTag.ReadWrite.All

But these permissions are not present in the list of permission in the **Graph Explorer** under **Modify Permission**.

So, **Q1: is it not possible to run the API from Graph Explorer ?**

Plus, I added permission to my application on Azure and then call the API in my angular application - it still gave me 404.

**Q2: What practice should I follow to make this API run?**

**EDIT:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamworktag-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http) doc Delegated permission is not supported to run this API, so we tried with Postman and this method returned a `200 OK` response code and a collection of teamworkTag objects in the response body.

Steps followed:

1. Added TeamworkTag.ReadWrite.All application permission n our Azure App.
2. Get access token as per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0#4-get-an-access-token)
3. Run this query in Postman.

   GET [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{teamid}/tags](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7Bteamid%7D/tags)
   [image]

Comment: Tried the same as stated above - also, edited the question above, I could be doing the step 1 wrong can you explain that?

Comment: Please check if you have given the right application graph permission to the app in azure from which you are getting bearer token and passing in the GET api call

Comment: yeah, it worked for me, I have to access_token first based on that application. Just one question. `1. Why I cannot use graph explorer  for the same, and application permissions are not visible there?`

Comment: Graph Explorer does not support application-level authorization. Follow this doc for more detailed explanation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/security-authorization

Comment: Can you have a look in this post related to tags APi only https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70448567/unable-to-run-list-teamworktags-api-in-my-angular-application