# Unable to run "List teamworkTags" API in my angular application

Tags: angular, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to run the below API:

> GET
> https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/53c53217-fe77-4383-bc5a-ed4937a1aecd/tags

but getting 404

Getting motivation from the post [List teamworkTags API returning 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70259330/list-teamworktags-api-returning-404) which I raised previously - I was able to run the API by `Get access without a user`.

This time I am trying to run the API through the current Angular App which runs in MS Teams. So far I have added the below to my service in Azure

> Application Permission - TeamworkTag.Read.All,
> TeamworkTag.ReadWrite.All

Corresponding to that I am able to see the permission on the consent page of the app as seen below, and consent was given successfully.

[image]

But when I try to run the API in the Angular app it gives me below with `404 Not Found`

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "NotFound",
        "message": "Request API is not supported.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2021-12-21T15:03:36",
            "request-id": "63e5a0e1-5e2d-4d29-a702-f147f0bc3fc8",
            "client-request-id": "63e5a0e1-5e2d-4d29-a702-f147f0bc3fc8"
        }
    }
}
```

**What I am doing wrong here?**

**As this is an application type permission, not the delegated one, something else needs to be done with scope or app roles?**

Comment: We tried this using Postman, It worked fine. Could you please try the same with postman and let us know if you are getting same error. https://i.stack.imgur.com/nf7Jd.png

Comment: how you are getting the `access_token` via `without a user`?

Comment: Yes I am following this documentation to get access token - [Get an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0#4-get-an-access-token)

Comment: Okay so, as mentioned in the question I am able to run using the access_token received from `without a user.` but I am looking at how it will work with application as described above?

Comment: Or, the only way to run this API is through [Get access without a user] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service?view=graph-rest-1.0#4-get-an-access-token)

Comment: Please go through the following samples to get access token for applications - https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/graph-rsc/nodeJs/auth.js, https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/graph-rsc/csharp/RSCDemo/Controllers/HomeController.cs

Answer (score 0):

Moving comment to answer for better visibility.

Please go through the following samples to get access token for applications -

1. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/graph-rsc/nodeJs/auth.js
2. https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/graph-rsc/csharp/RSCDemo/Controllers/HomeController.cs